# List of all country names with 2-letter symbols

Tags: mysql

I searched for an array of all country names with the 2-letter symbols but I didn't find one. I want to add it to a table in a MySQL database.

Comment: What symbols are you talking about?

Comment: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/ ?

Comment: Countries Short like UK for United Kingdom etc

Comment: @eggyal gave you the list, you just need to parse it now :)

Comment: @sp00m: It's available as a delimited text file from that site, so can be imported using [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) or [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html).

Comment: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/tree/master/country/cldr/en

Comment: @LasseVKarisen: Can you help me understand why this question has been closed?  It seems to me that it very much *can* "be reasonably answered in its current form" (as indeed I have done).  Perhaps I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refining your search to include things like "countries database", "country list sql", "iso". These databases are available, and the data itself is also freely available on the internet. However, if you can't find a database for free like the one you are looking for, you could certainly build one very quickly with the existing available data.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO 3166 list of country names and 2-character abbreviations is available from [their website](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/).  I suggest you use the [semicolon delimited TXT format](http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt) and then import into MySQL using either [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) or [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html).  For example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/list-en1-semic-3.txt'
    INTO TABLE countries
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    IGNORE 2 LINES
    (country_name, abbreviation);
```

Or:

```bsh
mysqlimport --columns="country_name,abbreviation" --fields-terminated-by=";" \
            --ignore-lines=2 my_db /path/to/countries.txt
```